# Sort an array of array and put the items into a chart

Tags: javascript

I'm using PlotlyJS to generate a simple line chart. The data that I need comes from an array of array. My javascript skills are not strong.

Using the console log I can see the array:

[image]

The problem is that I need to sort it based on id(see the console.log belove).

Firstly I've created a for loop:

```
for (data in ndvi_array) {
  console.log('id: '+ndvi_array[data][0]+', data: '+ndvi_array[data][1]+', index: '+ndvi_array[data][2]);

    var data = [
      {
        x: ndvi_array[data][1],
        y: ndvi_array[data][2],
        type: 'scatter'
      }
    ];

    Plotly.newPlot('ndvi-index', data);

};
```

Then I've tried to sort my arrays using this code inside for loop:

```
console.log(ndvi_array[data][0].sort((a,b)=>a-b));
```

When I use this I see the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: ndvi_array[data][0].sort is not a function

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying sort method it is working on value rather than on array.

let suppose we have an array:
x = [[6],[2]]

- x[0] - We are accessing first value which is an array [6]
- x[0][0] - we are accessing first value of first array which is 6

if we try x[0][0].sort() we will get error as sort is array method.

Correct one :

```
x = [[6],[2],[1],[8]]
x.sort(function(a,b){ return a[0]- b[0] })
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort array of array-based on `index` we want to use in the example we only have `1` value in an array of the array so we will use `0` `index` of the array:

```js
let ndvi_array = [[0], [5], [3], [1], [9]]
let sortedArray = ndvi_array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[0] - a[0];
});
console.log(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `sort` your input array (ndvi_array) as follows -

```js
var inputArray = [
  [2, 'abc', 123],
  [12, 'abd', 124],
  [1, 'abe', 125],
  [7, 'abf', 126]
]

inputArray.sort(([id1], [id2]) => id1 - id2)

console.log(inputArray)
```

Comment: With your indications I see the same error: `Uncaught TypeError: ndvi_array[data][0].sort is not a function`

Comment: Yes because ndvi_array[data][0] is not an array, just use ndvi_array.sort(....)